# Select current value of CSS based Switch

Tags: jquery, css

This may be a daft question (hopefully not though).

I am new to javascript / jQuery at the minute, and I came across the following site which creates easy to configure On/Off Switches:

http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

The switch is really good, but how do I use jQuery to determine whether the switch is On or Off? As far as I can tell nothing is actually changing, so there is no value etc. to collect.

Comment: The `right` value of class `onoffswitch-switch` seem to change from 56px to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch contains a (hidden) `input type="checkbox"`, and it is that element that triggers the style change.

Using [Vanilla JavaScript](http://vanilla-js.com/) or jQuery, select the checkbox and see if it's checked (JS: `.checked`, jQ: `.prop("checked")`)

Comment: I'd say `.prop('checked')` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: @kapa So would I. Can you tell I don't use jQuery? :p

Comment: Oh, now I see I attempted to correct the master of Vanilla Javascript. Sorry for the jQuery nonsense (and +1) ;).

Comment: Cheers for that, it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the HTML, there is an underlying checkbox.

The checkbox has a property named `checked` that is either true or false. You need to check that.

[This little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9m6bk/) might help (check the console to see the result).

```
$('.onoffswitch input').change(function () {
    console.log(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at there is not actually JavaScript at all, but a CSS animation. The button is actually a label for a hidden input element with a CSS-based animation triggered when the label is checked.

To determine whether or not that is the case you would do something like the following:

```
if( $('.onoffswitch-checkbox').prop('checked') ){
    doSomething();
}
```